# IOS 8: doesn't sent emails

Tags: objective-c, email, ios8

my IOS app has a button to send emails - running on IOS 6,7 it works fine but
on devices running IOS 8 the email opens, no error appear in app or logs, but the email is not being received

I've been googling it as well as looked in apple site as well as other tutorials I don't see any differences from what I have written... any ideas?

```
- (IBAction) emailBtn_Click:(id)sender
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *emailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == YES)
    {
        [emailComposer setSubject:@"hi"];
        [emailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

        [self presentViewController:emailComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Open Email");
    }
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"e-mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"e-mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"e-mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"e-mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, may help you

```
- (IBAction) emailBtn_Click:(id)sender
{

if([self canDeviceSendEmail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Report"];
    [picker setTitle:@""];
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithString:@"Message"];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]];
    [picker setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{


    }];
}
else{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:@"You must have an email account configured to use this feature."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
}

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
     didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                   error:(NSError*)error {

//[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
}
- (BOOL)canDeviceSendEmail{
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
return mailClass != nil && [mailClass canSendMail];
}
```